# pandas - determine the duration of an event

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Panadas DataFrame containing the measurements (Val) of various operations (OpID) with the time-stamp for when the measurement occurred (OpTime).

```
OpID              OpTime  Val
 143 2014-01-01 02:35:02   20
 143 2014-01-01 02:40:01   24
 143 2014-01-01 02:40:03   0
 143 2014-01-01 02:45:01   0
 143 2014-01-01 02:50:01   20
 143 2014-01-01 02:55:01   0
 143 2014-01-01 03:00:01   20
 143 2014-01-01 03:05:01   24
 143 2014-01-01 03:10:01   20
 212 2014-01-01 02:15:01   20
 212 2014-01-01 02:17:02   0
 212 2014-01-01 02:20:01   0
 212 2014-01-01 02:25:01   0
 212 2014-01-01 02:30:01   20
 299 2014-01-01 03:30:03   33
 299 2014-01-01 03:35:02   33
 299 2014-01-01 03:40:01   34
 299 2014-01-01 03:45:01   33
 299 2014-01-01 03:45:02   34
```

My desire to to generate an output which only shows the time periods in which the measurement returned zero.  The Start column would show the first in a series of OpTimes which resulted in zero and End would contain the OpTime of the first Val that was non-zero.

Given the above sample data my desired result is:

```
OpID                      Start                     End
 143        2014-01-01 02:40:03     2014-01-01 02:50:01
 143        2014-01-01 02:55:01     2014-01-01 03:00:01
 212        2014-01-01 02:17:02     2014-01-01 02:30:01
```

Comment: What if the last measurement in a group is zero?

Comment: Ideally the result would include a row for that either with a null, NaN, or the OpTime in the End column. I would consider that case as "extra credit" though, for my current needs a correct answer would not need to handle that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `pivot()`?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['Zeros'] = (df['Val']==0)
df['Valdf'] = np.hstack((nan, diff(df['Zeros'].values))) #how do you treat the first cell?
df['Valdr'] = np.hstack((diff(df['Zeros'].values), nan)) #how do you treat the last cell?
pf2 = pd.concat([df[((df['Zeros']!=True)&(df['Valdf']==1))],df[((df['Zeros'])&(df['Valdr']==1))]]).sort_index()
pf2['State'] = np.where(pf2['Zeros'], 'Start', 'End')
pf2['idx2'] = pf2['OpID'] + np.arange(len(pf2))/2*0.00000001 #need unique index for .pivot()
print pf2.pivot(index='idx2', columns='State', values='OpTime')
```

---

```
State                  End                Start
idx2                                           
143.0  2014-01-01 02:50:01  2014-01-01 02:45:01
143.1  2014-01-01 03:00:01  2014-01-01 02:55:01
212.2  2014-01-01 02:30:01  2014-01-01 02:25:01
```

To get the one you presented, probably just:

```
pf3 = pd.DataFrame(pf2.pivot(index='idx2', columns='State', values='OpTime'))
pf3.index=asarray(pf3.index.values, 'int')
```

Comment: This solution depends on the assumption that `End` and `Start` occur in pairs in your time series. The situation @DSM described surely is a situation that will break this assumption. Besides that, you may also need to think about what to do with the first time point being zero. I don't know if you want to treat it as a `start`, because the system may (potentially) already be in the `val==0` state before you start to take measurement. Anyway, just a few thoughts. It all depends on your application and the real world problem.

Comment: Works great!  Thanks for the help.  I may need to handle those edge cases of first and last measurements with a zero as I bring in more data but this does just what I need now.  I did make an edit to the "unique value" multiplier as 0.1 was rolling over which caused problems so I used 0.00000001 instead.